# Question requiring knowledge of Industry vet

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

I asked a question in the [workplace](http://workplace.stackexchange.com) site. It was put on hold as off topic. Where does my question belong?

It is about whether or not experience from one programming language carries over when switching to a job with a different language. The question was:

> I am about to leave school and get my first job in the industry. I
>   currently have two offers. One of which uses Java and pays well. The
>   other uses C# and pays about $10k less starting. Java is OK, but I
>   prefer C#. If I take the Java job, I will make more money, but my C#
>   skills will cease improving. In the future, I may decide that I want
>   to take a C# job. Will taking the Java job limit my C# options in the
>   future? If so, to what severity?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This kind of question is generally not suitable for Stack Exchange sites.

It is not really answerable - you are asking us to predict the future. No one can do that.

Comment: I don't think so. What if I phrased it: "I am a senior level Java developer. Am I also qualified to get a job as a senior level C# developer?"

Comment: @Evorlor - nothing to do with it. You are asking us "what will happen if?". I fear my crystal ball is broken right now...

Comment: I think I may have poorly worded my question. What I meant to ask is whether Java experience translates to C# experience in the industry in terms of getting an equal job

Comment: @Evorlor - again, entirely subjective. And different per company. One company might not touch you with a barge poll if you have Java experience, other will not care one way or another, so longer as you can program and am smart.

Comment: I think that is about as clear an answer available until you fix your crystal ball. Thanks oded!

Comment: It's not even universal across a company. There might be some tendencies that apply to entire companies, but it depends much more on the hiring manager. Some put a lot of emphasis on specific technical skills. Others put more emphasis on fundamental knowledge and talent, and believe that smart people can pick up specific skills quickly.